# Hide out of stock products

Tags: magento-1.9, category, collection, product-collection

I want to hide out of stock products from showing in search or category pages and I do not want to use the built in feature:

```
Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Stock Options
Display Out of Stock product -> No
```

The reason is that I use and sort out of stock products and if I disable them completely I can't filter by Stock status.

How do I put a filter on the category and search collection?

Answer (score 1):

I have done it and I know it will help a lot of people so this is what I did to achieve this:

Firstly you need to modify the collection which is loaded in:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php
```

You're best making a local copy and editing that:

```
app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php
```

Find this line:

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
```

Directly under it place this code:

```
$in_Collection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock',1);

$in_Products = array();
foreach($in_Collection as $_collection) {
        $in_Products[] = $_collection->getProductId();
}

$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$in_Products));
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

@Mike Tim Turner any idea how to get your solution to work in Magento 2.4.2?

Answer (score -1):

you can put a **if condition** in your `list.phtml` file

start the condition before **li tag**

```
<ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>  <!-- Added condition here -->
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
```

and then close this condition after **li tag**

```
      </li>
     <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ol>
```

Comment: I already did that but the problem is that the category pages end up only showing about 5 products per page instead of showing on the same page if that makes sense.

Comment: This is not a good solution, you're simply hiding the products in the template. A better solution would be to exclude them from the product collection.

Comment: @mizuti Read the question first. He was asking to hide the products from category pages (templates). If you want to give him better suggestion then add comment below his question.